# boost::variant comparison with contained value

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to find a way to compare boost::variant with underlying value without constructing variant from this underlying value. The question is defined in the comment in "main()" function
And auxiliary question is about the comparison operators defined in the code. How to decrease the # of comparison operators? If boost::variant contains, say, 6 different types, do I have to define 6! operators to be able to compare two variants?

Thanks!

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
namespace test {

    namespace Tag {
        struct Level1{ int t{ 1 }; };
        struct Level2{ int t{ 2 }; };
    }

    template <typename Kind> struct Node;

    using LevelOne = Node<Tag::Level1>;
    using LevelTwo = Node<Tag::Level2>;

    using VariantNode = boost::variant
    <
        boost::recursive_wrapper<LevelOne>,
        boost::recursive_wrapper<LevelTwo>
    >;

    typedef VariantNode* pTree;
    typedef std::vector<pTree> lstTree;

    template <typename Kind> struct Node
    {
        Node(pTree p, std::string n) : parent(p), name(n) {}
        Node(const Node& another) : name(another.name), parent(another.parent) {}
        virtual ~Node() {}
        std::string name;
        pTree parent;
    };

    bool operator == (const LevelOne& one, const LevelTwo& two) {
        return false;
    }
    bool operator == (const LevelTwo& two, const LevelOne& one) {
        return false;
    }
    bool operator == (const LevelOne& one, const LevelOne& two) {
        return true;
    }
    bool operator == (const LevelTwo& one, const LevelTwo& two) {
        return true;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    using namespace test;
    LevelOne l1(nullptr, "level one");
    VariantNode tl2 = VariantNode(LevelTwo(nullptr, "level two"));
    VariantNode tl1 = VariantNode(LevelOne(nullptr, "level one"));
    bool rv = (tl1 == tl2); // this line compiles OK (comparing two variants)
    // comparison below does not compile, because "l1" is not a variant. 
    // Question: How can I compare "variant" value "tl1" 
    // with one of the possible content values "l1"
    bool rv1 = (tl1 == l1); 
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Your `bool operator==(...)` can be templated. In fact, you don't need any custom template magic, just return `std::is_same<T1, T2>::value`.

Comment: @lorro - thanks! Comparison is now defined as:
template<typename F, typename S> bool operator == (const F& f, const S& s) {
  bool issame = std::is_same<F, S>::value;
  if (!issame)
   return false;

  return f.name == s.name;
 }

remaining question - how to compare boost::variant with underlying value without constructing variant out of this value?

Comment: use `get<>()` (if I get you right).

Comment: to use boost::get<> I need to know the type of the variable I am comparing variant with. In the post code sample the type is LevelOne, but I need to be able to do the comparison generically. For example I need to compare value of type boost::variant<int, std::string> with either string or integer.

Comment: You don't need to know the type, you can write a template again. But it's probably easier to write a (templated) visitor for it.

Comment: @lorro - thanks for your help! Your last comment is unclear to me. I'll appreciate a blueprint for templated visitor that uses both variant and underlying types for comparison.

Comment: Something to start with,... `template<typename T> struct One { const T& m_one; One(const T& one) : m_one(one) {} template<typename T2> operator(const T2& t2) { ... } };`, you need to fill the `...` with checking types and values. You can use it via `variant.apply_visitor(One(elem));`.

Answer (score 3):

The following will work with any number of types in the variant:

```
template<typename T>
struct equality_visitor : boost::static_visitor<bool> {
    explicit constexpr equality_visitor(T const& t) noexcept : t_{ &t } { }

    template<typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, U>::value>* = nullptr>
    constexpr bool operator ()(U const& u) const {
        return *t_ == u;
    }

    template<typename U, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<T, U>::value>* = nullptr>
    constexpr bool operator ()(U const&) const {
        return false;
    }

private:
    T const* t_;
};

template<
    typename T,
    typename... Ts,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<
        boost::mpl::contains<typename boost::variant<Ts...>::types, T>::value
    >
>
bool operator ==(T const& t, boost::variant<Ts...> const& v) {
    equality_visitor<T> ev{ t };
    return v.apply_visitor(ev);
}

template<
    typename T,
    typename... Ts,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<
        boost::mpl::contains<typename boost::variant<Ts...>::types, T>::value
    >
>
bool operator !=(T const& t, boost::variant<Ts...> const& v) {
    return !(t == v);
}
```

The catch is that comparisons must always be of the form `value == variant` or `value != variant` rather than `variant == value` or `variant != value`. This is because `boost::variant<>` itself defines these operators to always `static_assert`, and there is no way for us to make a global operator more specialized than `variant<>`'s built-in ones.

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3745c4983c4f38f6)</kbd>

Comment: @lidjarn - thank you! It compiles and runs in vs2013 (without constexpr ).  I did not work with variadic templates, so I am studying the code. Big help!